# My OnTriggerEnter2D is not working- Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, scripting, unityscript

I have a script that plays a sound when the player enters the portal:

```
function OnTriggerEnter2D (other : Collider2D) {
    if(other.name == "Blue Portal") {
        audio.PlayOneShot(portalSound);
        score.GetComponent(Score).scoreNumber += 1;
        Debug.Log("LOL");
    }
}
```

It doesn't respond to the collision and not showing the Debug.Log. I have checked the is trigger box for the portal. I tried everything but its just not working. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

First remove all the collider Components and rigidbody component then re-implement Rigidbody2D and Boxcollider2D (with true checkbox On Trigger). Then it will works.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably due to how rigidbodies on these objects are set up (or the lack of them). Check a [table from this answer](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/575868/2d-collisionstriggers-are-confusing-me.html) for details.

Comment: I've tried adding Rigidbody2d before and setting it to kinematic. I'm still confused.

Comment: You're only talking about one object. What about the other?